# understanding selenium chaining call

Tags: selenium-webdriver, methods, call, chaining

I am confused about the implicit call which is chain call:
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

driver.manager(); return a interface type "Options", which is not object.
I cannot understand why call timeOuts() method, because "Options" is not an object, is an interface. Did I miss something?

Comment: What do you think an interface is, if not an object?

Comment: Interface is just set of methods, could be used as a type.

Comment: What language are you working in?  It's not at all obvious, and it makes a big difference.